# Will the chromecast play media segment files (.ts) from an m3u8 playlist?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I've noticed a lot of websites use m3u8 playlists on their html5 video tags, and those segment files inside the playlist appear to be h264 encoded, so I'm guessing the container is the only thing that the chromecast doesn't support in this case although I know very little about video containers and codecs so I'm probably just making no sense. So with all this in mind, is there any chance the chromecast will one day play those files?

Here is an example http://stream.gravlab.net/003119/sparse/v1d30/posts/2014/barcelona/barcelona.m3u8

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - You can using either the [default Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default), a [Styled Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver), or in a [Custom Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) and using the [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player).  Of course, you (the owner of the data) must turn on [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers for the m3u8 manifest, any sub-manifests, and for the segments and any keys on your server / CDN to support this.  This requirement is due to our player being written in JavaScript and running in Chrome on the Chromecast device.

Note - for the Default Receiver & Styled Receiver, the URL to allow CORS from is www.gstatic.com.  For your Custom Receiver, it will be the URL where you host your Receiver.